What is the difference between "because of ..." and "due to ..."?
I have one sentence:

Due to climate change, the emperor penguin is under threat.

May I write above sentence like this?

Because of climate change, the emperor penguin is under threat.

What is the difference between "because of ..." and "due to ..." in general? I was reading somewhere that "due to ..." modifies nouns and "because of ..." does verbs. Am I right or not?
